# Run Method from onClick of a List Item Android

Tags: android, android-listview, onclick

How do you run a method from the OnClick of a list item?

My method is called CallEmergency()

```
public void CallEmergency(View arg0) {
        String phone_no = "911";
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone_no));
        callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }
```

I can start other activities with:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity.class);
                    startActivity(i);}
```

but I'd like to just run this CallEmergency() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    callEmergency(null);
}
```

(Please read about [Java naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm), which state that methods like `callEmergency()` should start with lower case letter.)

Comment: Lame, was missing the NULL! Thanks for the help and edu Sam :)